Looking for the asymptotic solution of $x \log (x)-(x+n) \log (x-n)=0$
Working this problem on Mathematics Stack Exchange, I very quickly obtained as an estimate of $x$ solution of
$$x \log (x)-(x+n) \log (x-n)=0$$
$$x_n^{(0)}=n+\sqrt n+\frac 14 \log(n)+\frac 12 \tag 1$$
The problem is that, if I try to continue, Mathematica is just running for ever. I suppose that this is because the next steps would/could involve some $\log(\log(n))$ terms. I must confess that I do not see where could be the problem.
By the end, I solved the problem  using $x_n^{(0)}=n+\sqrt n$ and it worked like a charm.
My question is : just by pure curiosity, how could I overcome this problem in order to have a better approximation ?
Edit
Limiting the problem to the first iterate of Newton method (my plan was to use Householder), here is my code
F[x_]:=x*Log[x] - (x+n)*Log[x-nx]
dF[x_]=D[F[x],x];
G[x_]:=x-F[x]/dF[x]
a = n+ Sqrt[n]+1/4 Log[n] + 1/2;
Asymptotic[G[a],{n,Infinity,2}]


Can you please edit the question and include Mathematica code that you used (and that seems to be running forever)?

@Domen. I made a simplified version of it (my plan was to use at least Householder.

While I don't have the exact answer to your question, in analyzing this issue I came across a bug, that is worth posting.
Numerically, everything works out and the accuracy of the approximation gradually improves
 Clear[g]; g[x_] := x*Log[x] - (n + x)*Log[x - n]; 
 x0 = n + Sqrt[n]; 
 x1 = Simplify[x0 - g[x]/D[g[x], x] /. x -> x0];
 x2 = Simplify[x1 - g[x]/D[g[x], x] /. x -> x1];
 x3 = Simplify[x2 - g[x]/D[g[x], x] /. x -> x2];
 x4 = Simplify[x3 - g[x]/D[g[x], x] /. x -> x3];

If we choose e.g. n=1000, the exact result is
 With[{n = 1000}, x /. FindRoot[{x*Log[x] - (n + x)*Log[x - n] == 0}, {x, n + 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 50]]
 (* 1034.0826406526080623397867143470439569472108249173 *)

and the approximations are
 N[x1 /. n -> 1000, 50]
 N[x2 /. n -> 1000, 50]
 N[x3 /. n -> 1000, 50]
 N[x4 /. n -> 1000, 50]

 (* 1033.9878620416309749896684806390203508433695809826 *)
 (* 1034.0825029243474732822359916223108059225685439416 *)
 (* 1034.0826406523174684342535403639694356716135619753 *)
 (* 1034.0826406526080623397854207087771913543850624828 *)

But the expressions for x2, x3 and x4 are extremely complicated.

Therefore, we will try to use the Series
  Series[x1, {n, Infinity, 1}]


  Series[x2, {n, Infinity, 1}]


We now have the following limits

I wanted to do something similar with the x3 expression, but I discovered a strange thing
 Limit[(x3 - (1/2 + Sqrt[n] + n + Log[n]/4)), n -> Infinity]
 (* 0 *)

 Limit[(x3 - (1/2 + Sqrt[n] + n + Log[n]/4))*n^(1/2), n -> Infinity]
 (* \[Infinity] *)

 Limit[(x3 - (1/2 + Sqrt[n] + n + Log[n]/4))*n^(49/100), n -> Infinity]
 (* 0 *)

 Limit[(x3 - (1/2 + Sqrt[n] + n + Log[n]/4))*n^(1/2)*Log[n], n -> Infinity]
 (* 0 *)

If the second limit is infinity and if I multiply the expression by log(n), I must also get infinity, but Mathematica gives 0. That's a bug!


I reported the bug noted in this response.

Thank you very much ! This ia a nice and interestinf work. Cheers :-)

Just for sportive interest, let us find the next term of the asymptotic expansion of the real
root of the equation x*Log[x] - (x + n)*Log[x - n]==0 as n tends to infinity.
We begin from
eq1 = 0 == x*Log[x] - (x + n)*Log[x - n] /. x -> n*(t + 1);

with small t.
Now
PowerExpand[Simplify[eq1]]


n (2 + t) (Log[n] + Log[t]) == n (1 + t) (Log[n] + Log[1 + t])

eq2 = Simplify[Series[n  (2 + t)  (Log[n] + Log[t]) == 
n  (1 + t)  (Log[n] + Log[1 + t]), {t, 0, 1}] // Normal]


n (-t + Log[n] + (2 + t) Log[t]) == 0

Unfortunately,
AsymptoticSolve[eq2, t,  n -> Infinity, Reals]

fails with this transcendental equation.
In order to overcome that difficulty, we notice that
some terms of the equation approach zero as t tends to zero:
AsymptoticEquivalent[eq2[[1]], n*(Log[n] + 2*Log[t]), t -> 0]


True

Now
Solve[n*(Log[n] + 2*Log[t]) == 0, t, Reals, Assumptions -> n >= 1]


{{t -> 1/Sqrt[n]}}

In order to obtain a better approximation, we put
eq3 = 0 == x*Log[x] - (x + n)*Log[x - n] /. 
x -> n*(1/Sqrt[n]*(1 + s) + 1);

Then, as previously,
eq4 = Simplify[Normal[Series[eq3, {s, 0, 1}]] // PowerExpand]

2 n s ==  1/2 Sqrt[n] (2 (1 + Sqrt[n] + s) Log[1 + 1/Sqrt[n]] + (1 + s) Log[n])
Reduce[eq4 && n > 1, s, Reals]


n > 1 &&  s == (8 n Log[1 + 1/Sqrt[n]] + 4 Log[1 + 1/Sqrt[n]]^2 +  4 Log[1 + 1/Sqrt[n]] Log[n] + Log[n]^2)/(16 n -  4 Log[1 + 1/Sqrt[n]]^2 - 4 Log[1 + 1/Sqrt[n]] Log[n] -  Log[n]^2) +  2 \[Sqrt]((16 n Log[1 + 1/Sqrt[n]]^2 + 16 n Log[1 + 1/Sqrt[n]]^3 +  4 n Log[1 + 1/Sqrt[n]]^4 + 16 n Log[1 + 1/Sqrt[n]] Log[n] +  16 n Log[1 + 1/Sqrt[n]]^2 Log[n] +  4 n Log[1 + 1/Sqrt[n]]^3 Log[n] + 4 n Log[n]^2 +  4 n Log[1 + 1/Sqrt[n]] Log[n]^2 +  n Log[1 + 1/Sqrt[n]]^2 Log[n]^2)/(16 n -  4 Log[1 + 1/Sqrt[n]]^2 - 4 Log[1 + 1/Sqrt[n]] Log[n] -  Log[n]^2)^2)

Finally,
Series[%[[2, 2]], {n, Infinity, 1}, Assumptions -> n > 1] // Normal


(2 + Log[n])/(4 Sqrt[n]) + (4 + 2 Log[n] + Log[n]^2)/(16 n)

and
Expand[n*(1/Sqrt[n]*(1 + s) + 1) /. 
 s -> (2 + Log[n])/(4 Sqrt[n]) + (4 + 2 Log[n] + Log[n]^2)/(16 n)]


1/2 + 1/(4 Sqrt[n]) + Sqrt[n] + n + Log[n]/4 + Log[n]/(8 Sqrt[n]) +  Log[n]^2/(16 Sqrt[n])

To be sure, let us verify it:
1/2 + 1/(4 Sqrt[n]) + Sqrt[n] + n + Log[n]/4 + Log[n]/
(8 Sqrt[n]) +  Log[n]^2/(16 Sqrt[n]) /. n -> 10000.


10102.9

n*(1 + 1/Sqrt[n] + 1/(2 n) + Log[n]/(4 n)) /. n -> 10000.


10102.8

NSolve[0 == x*Log[x] - (x + n)*Log[x - n] /. n -> 10000, x, Reals]


10102.9


Thank you very much ! This helps. Cheers :-)

The series expansion seems to be
$$
x = n+\sqrt{n}+
    \frac{\log (n)+2}{4}+
    \frac{3 \log ^2(n)+8 \log (n)+12}{32 \sqrt{n}}+
    \frac{2 \log ^3(n)+6 \log ^2(n)+15\log (n)+12}{48 n}+
    \frac{125 \log ^4(n)+400 \log ^3(n)+1320 \log ^2(n)+1728 \log (n)+1232}{6144 n^{3/2}} + \ldots
$$
but I don't have a good way of deriving it, other than tedious term addition. To show that it works,
f[n_, x_] = x Log[x] - (x + n) Log[x - n];
y[n_] = n + Sqrt[n] +
        (2 + Log[n])/4 +
        (12 + 8 Log[n] + 3 Log[n]^2)/(32 Sqrt[n]) +
        (12 + 15 Log[n] + 6 Log[n]^2 + 2 Log[n]^3)/(48 n) +
        (1232 + 1728 Log[n] + 1320 Log[n]^2 + 400 Log[n]^3 + 125 Log[n]^4)/(6144 n^(3/2));

Asymptotic[f[n, y[n]], n -> ∞]
(*    (27 Log[n]^5)/(1280 n^(3/2))    *)


Thank you ! To be tedious, it is, for sure. Cheers :-)

@Roman Nice answer!  It can even be a bit shorter! Asymptotic [   f[n, n + Sqrt[n]  + 1/4  Log[n] + 1/2 + 3/32 Log[n]^2/Sqrt[n] +      1/4 Log[n] /Sqrt[n] + 3/8 1/Sqrt[n] ], {n, Infinity,     1}  ] // Simplify gives Log[n]^3/(12 Sqrt[n])

@UlrichNeumann yes; but I gave some higher-order terms too (yours match the first three lines of what I gave).

@Roman Yes agreed, I only tried to point out that this is the simplest solution which gives a vanishing asymoptot of f[n,x]
